# In SQL, how to increment a value that is a number, but set a value to 1 if it's null?

Tags: php, sql, isnull

The title explains it. I want to update a column value to add +1 to itself if it is a number, but if it is currently null, change it to a 1. This is what I've tried so far:
`"UPDATE table SET colname=ISNULL(colname, 0)+1 WHERE othercolname IN('$val', '$val2')";`
I'm fairly new to SQL and have looked at a bunch of things, but can't get it to work.

Comment: What is the number that you want to increment? Is it the next number in the column or just +1 the number that you are passing to SQL?

Comment: *but can't get it to work* - what does this actually mean? Your SQL statement looks fine.

Comment: Your code looks fine except for the fact that you are not using prepared statements and parameterized queries, so your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Not too worried about sql injection, this is just on a local network. The answer is down below, my original syntax was bad as far as I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you want to use CASE/WHEN/ELSE

```
UPDATE table SET colname = (CASE colname WHEN  NULL THEN 1 ELSE colname + 1 END) WHERE othercolname IN('$val', '$val2')
```

To add more detail, your query sets colname to the return value of `ISNULL(colname, 0)+1`.  The ISNULL function takes only one parameter and returns 1 if that parameter is NULL and 0 if it is not NULL.  Then you are adding 1.  You will get an 'incorrect parameter count' error and if you fix that you would still only get 2's for NULL values and 1's for everything else.  So contrary to popular opinion that query does not look fine.

Comment: I couldn't get your exact syntax to work, but that sent me down the right path and I figured it out. The syntax I ended up using was this: `"UPDATE table SET colname = (CASE WHEN colname IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE colname + 1 END) WHERE othercol IN ('$var1', '$var2')";`

Comment: @justdoingmyjob well done!  I think the syntax I posted is a shorthand that does not work as universally across different data bases as yours.  Thanks for the accepted answer and good luck with your project.

Comment: Thank you, greatly appreciated your answer!